# React-Native ViewPagerAndroid function componentDidMount belonging to last page is called when first page is shown

Tags: android, react-native

My `ViewPagerAndroid` has four pages (1-4).

The function `componentDidMount` belongs to page 4 which I used for loading user information from the server.

I want to get information when I see page 4, but now, this function is called when I see page 1.

Comment: Use componentWillReceiveProps instead

Comment: Fix spelling/grammar/title/tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use componentWillReceiveProps instead.
Now my problem solved.

```
<MePage
      key={i}
      onShowing={this.state.currentKey === this.props.items[i].key}
      navigator={this.props.navigator}
    />

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.onShowing) {
      alert('hi');
    }
}
```